# Refresh Media source in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am using `Exo Player` `ExtractorMediaSource` for playing video in my android app.  I am downloading media from server and save in local database and on a specific time Alarm i play this media using `ConcatenatingMediaSource` in exo player. but first i check that all video file downloaded or not and start player with downloaded media source . and if any video is not downloaded then i want to download it in background at when it downloaded then i want to add this video in my already created playlist

**This is sample code**

```
  private void playAndUpdateVideo(ArrayList<String> mediaSourc) {



        simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setDefaultArtwork(null);

        mainHandler = new Handler();
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector( videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "com.cloveritservices.hype"), bandwidthMeter);
// 2. Create a default LoadControl
        extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

// 3. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        player.addListener(this);

//Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
// Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);




        MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[mediaSourc.size()];
        for (int i=0;i<mediaSourc.size();i++)
        {

            mediaSources[i]= buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaSourc.get(i)));

        }

        MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
                : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
        LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare(loopingSource);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("switch", false);
        if (!isChecked)
        player.setVolume(0f);
        else player.setVolume(2f);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

And here i am checking for video file that it is downloaded or not

```
 if (CommonUtils.isExternalStorageExistAndWritable()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < videoUrl.size(); i++) {


                    if (!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + Constants.PROFILE_VIDEO_FOLDER + CommonUtils.fileFromUrl(videoUrl.get(i))).exists() && !CommonUtils.currentlyDownloading(context,CommonUtils.fileFromUrl(videoUrl.get(i)))) {
                        downloadByDownloadManager(videoUrl.get(i), CommonUtils.fileFromUrl(videoUrl.get(i)));
                        if (flag==Constants.FLAG_PLAY){downloadFlag=true;}
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card not mounted.Please Mount SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (flag==Constants.FLAG_PLAY && !downloadFlag)
            {
                playAndUpdateVideo(videoUrl);
            }

  public void downloadByDownloadManager(String url, String fileName1) {
        downloadUrl=url;
        fileName=fileName1;
        request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("video file");
        request.setTitle(fileName);

        request.setNotificationVisibility(2);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Constants.PROFILE_VIDEO_FOLDER, fileName);
                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                    manager.enqueue(request);







        // get download service and enqueue file



    }
```

Please help that how to add missing video file later to playlist if it is not downloaded.

Comment: You want to add it to playlist after the file is downloaded?

Comment: yes but dont want to intialize playlist again@SagarPujari

Comment: can u share the code in which you are downloading the file.

Comment: please check i have added@SagarPujari

Comment: I think you need an event when the download is completed.

Comment: Implement downloading of file through link below you will get event in postexecute when download is completed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26210138/5279468 t

Comment: Thats not my problem . I have created listener for handling download response and i am getting all thing perfectly but unable to add that video file in playlist @SagarPujari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add new video files to your playlist, you need a new `MediaSource` implementation which can handle a list of sources to enable resizing. This is fairly simple to achieve, the easiest way to do so is to create a modified implementation of `ConcaternatingMediaSource` which uses lists instead of arrays to store and iterate over media sources. You then replace the `ConcaternatingMediaSource` in `playAndUpdateVideo` with the new implementation using lists. This will allow you to add and remove from your playlist as you wish, you can append new media files when your download complete listener is triggered. Here is the full class for a media source implementation using lists:

```
public final class DynamicMediaSource implements MediaSource {

    private List<MediaSource> mediaSources;
    private SparseArray<Timeline> timelines;
    private SparseArray<Object> manifests;
    private Map<MediaPeriod, Integer> sourceIndexByMediaPeriod;
    private SparseArray<Boolean> duplicateFlags;
    private boolean isRepeatOneAtomic;

    private Listener listener;
    private DynamicTimeline timeline;

    /**
     * @param mediaSources The {@link MediaSource}s to concatenate. It is valid for the same
     *     {@link MediaSource} instance to be present more than once in the array.
     */
    public DynamicMediaSource(List<MediaSource> mediaSources) {
        this(false, mediaSources);
    }

    /**
     * @param isRepeatOneAtomic Whether the concatenated media source shall be treated as atomic
     *     (i.e., repeated in its entirety) when repeat mode is set to {@code Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE}.
     * @param mediaSources The {@link MediaSource}s to concatenate. It is valid for the same
     *     {@link MediaSource} instance to be present more than once in the array.
     */
    public DynamicMediaSource(boolean isRepeatOneAtomic, List<MediaSource> mediaSources) {
        for (MediaSource mediaSource : mediaSources) {
            Assertions.checkNotNull(mediaSource);
        }
        this.mediaSources = mediaSources;
        this.isRepeatOneAtomic = isRepeatOneAtomic;
        timelines = new SparseArray<Timeline>();
        manifests = new SparseArray<Object>();
        sourceIndexByMediaPeriod = new HashMap<>();
        duplicateFlags = buildDuplicateFlags(mediaSources);
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareSource(ExoPlayer player, boolean isTopLevelSource, Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaSources.size(); i++) {
            if (!duplicateFlags.get(i)) {
                final int index = i;
                mediaSources.get(i).prepareSource(player, false, new Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSourceInfoRefreshed(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
                        handleSourceInfoRefreshed(index, timeline, manifest);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void maybeThrowSourceInfoRefreshError() throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaSources.size(); i++) {
            if (!duplicateFlags.get(i)) {
                mediaSources.get(i).maybeThrowSourceInfoRefreshError();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MediaPeriod createPeriod(MediaPeriodId id, Allocator allocator) {
        int sourceIndex = timeline.getChildIndexByPeriodIndex(id.periodIndex);
        MediaPeriodId periodIdInSource =
            new MediaPeriodId(id.periodIndex - timeline.getFirstPeriodIndexByChildIndex(sourceIndex));
        MediaPeriod mediaPeriod = mediaSources.get(sourceIndex).createPeriod(periodIdInSource, allocator);
        sourceIndexByMediaPeriod.put(mediaPeriod, sourceIndex);
        return mediaPeriod;
    }

    @Override
    public void releasePeriod(MediaPeriod mediaPeriod) {
        int sourceIndex = sourceIndexByMediaPeriod.get(mediaPeriod);
        sourceIndexByMediaPeriod.remove(mediaPeriod);
        mediaSources.get(sourceIndex).releasePeriod(mediaPeriod);
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseSource() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaSources.size(); i++) {
            if (!duplicateFlags.get(i)) {
                mediaSources.get(i).releaseSource();
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleSourceInfoRefreshed(int sourceFirstIndex, Timeline sourceTimeline,
                                       Object sourceManifest) {
        // Set the timeline and manifest.
        timelines.put(sourceFirstIndex, sourceTimeline);
        manifests.put(sourceFirstIndex, sourceManifest);

        // Also set the timeline and manifest for any duplicate entries of the same source.
        for (int i = sourceFirstIndex + 1; i < mediaSources.size(); i++) {
            if (mediaSources.get(i).equals(mediaSources.get(sourceFirstIndex))) {
                timelines.put(i, sourceTimeline);
                manifests.put(i, sourceManifest);
            }
        }

        for(int i= 0; i<mediaSources.size(); i++){
            if(timelines.get(i) == null){
                // Don't invoke the listener until all sources have timelines.
                return;
            }
        }

        timeline = new DynamicTimeline(timelines, isRepeatOneAtomic);
        listener.onSourceInfoRefreshed(timeline, new ArrayList(asList(manifests)));
    }

    private static SparseArray<Boolean> buildDuplicateFlags(List<MediaSource> mediaSources) {
        SparseArray<Boolean> duplicateFlags = new SparseArray<Boolean>();
        IdentityHashMap<MediaSource, Void> sources = new IdentityHashMap<>(mediaSources.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaSources.size(); i++) {
            MediaSource source = mediaSources.get(i);
            if (!sources.containsKey(source)) {
                sources.put(source, null);
                duplicateFlags.append(i,false);
            } else {
                duplicateFlags.append(i,true);
            }
        }
        return duplicateFlags;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link Timeline} that is the concatenation of one or more {@link Timeline}s.
     */
    public static final class DynamicTimeline extends AbstractConcatenatedTimeline {

        private final SparseArray<Timeline> timelines;
        private final int[] sourcePeriodOffsets;
        private final int[] sourceWindowOffsets;
        private final boolean isRepeatOneAtomic;

        public DynamicTimeline(SparseArray<Timeline> timelines, boolean isRepeatOneAtomic) {
            super(timelines.size());
            int[] sourcePeriodOffsets = new int[timelines.size()];
            int[] sourceWindowOffsets = new int[timelines.size()];
            long periodCount = 0;
            int windowCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < timelines.size(); i++) {
                Timeline timeline = timelines.get(i);
                periodCount += timeline.getPeriodCount();
                Assertions.checkState(periodCount <= Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                    "ConcatenatingMediaSource children contain too many periods");
                sourcePeriodOffsets[i] = (int) periodCount;
                windowCount += timeline.getWindowCount();
                sourceWindowOffsets[i] = windowCount;
            }
            this.timelines = timelines;
            this.sourcePeriodOffsets = sourcePeriodOffsets;
            this.sourceWindowOffsets = sourceWindowOffsets;
            this.isRepeatOneAtomic = isRepeatOneAtomic;
        }

        @Override
        public int getWindowCount() {
            return sourceWindowOffsets[sourceWindowOffsets.length - 1];
        }

        @Override
        public int getPeriodCount() {
            return sourcePeriodOffsets[sourcePeriodOffsets.length - 1];
        }

        @Override
        public int getNextWindowIndex(int windowIndex, @Player.RepeatMode int repeatMode) {
            if (isRepeatOneAtomic && repeatMode == Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE) {
                repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL;
            }
            return super.getNextWindowIndex(windowIndex, repeatMode);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPreviousWindowIndex(int windowIndex, @Player.RepeatMode int repeatMode) {
            if (isRepeatOneAtomic && repeatMode == Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE) {
                repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL;
            }
            return super.getPreviousWindowIndex(windowIndex, repeatMode);
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildIndexByPeriodIndex(int periodIndex) {
            return Util.binarySearchFloor(sourcePeriodOffsets, periodIndex, true, false) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected int getChildIndexByWindowIndex(int windowIndex) {
            return Util.binarySearchFloor(sourceWindowOffsets, windowIndex, true, false) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected int getChildIndexByChildUid(Object childUid) {
            if (!(childUid instanceof Integer)) {
                return C.INDEX_UNSET;
            }
            return (Integer) childUid;
        }

        @Override
        protected Timeline getTimelineByChildIndex(int childIndex) {
            return timelines.get(childIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public int getFirstPeriodIndexByChildIndex(int childIndex) {
            return childIndex == 0 ? 0 : sourcePeriodOffsets[childIndex - 1];
        }

        @Override
        protected int getFirstWindowIndexByChildIndex(int childIndex) {
            return childIndex == 0 ? 0 : sourceWindowOffsets[childIndex - 1];
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getChildUidByChildIndex(int childIndex) {
            return childIndex;
        }

    }

}
```

To check when the file is downloaded and set a download completed listener, you can use a `BroadcastReceiver`. [A detailed example of how to set up the BroadcastReceiver is provided here.](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)