# Why getUriForDownloadedFile() returns null

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I am downloading the picture via DownloadManager (API 28).
The picture is successfully downloaded and displayed in ImageView.
I want find out the file name. But getUriForDownloadedFile() return null.
Why?

```
private void dowloadfile() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(editText.getText().toString());
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "picture." + extension);

    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

    refid = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    Uri u = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(refid);
}
```

Comment: after enqueue, the download is a asyn operation, the uri might be assigned after the download has finished, you need to listen to your receiver and pass the id to get the uri

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! I forgot about multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after enqueue, the download is a asyn operation, the uri might be assigned after the download has finished, you need to listen to your receiver and pass the id to get the uri

Comment: How to add listener for the download has finished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210048/how-to-receive-status-of-download-manager-intent-until-download-success-or-faile